# Doppler cooling Ethanol

Tags: thermodynamics, laser, gas, cooling, laser-interaction

Is it possible to use laser cooling to cool Ethanol in it's gas phase? I've seen research on IR diode cooling when you reverse the electrodes but laser cooling was/has always been limited to atoms and a handful of diatomic molecules.

If you where to design a laser trap for ethanol, what would the Maxwell speed distribution and rms velocity be for ethanol gas molecules/atoms.

What would the d-line be? For sodium atoms if a laser is tuned just below one of the sodium d-lines (589.0 and 589.6 nm, about 2.1 eV), a sodium atom traveling toward the laser and absorbing a laser photon would have its momentum reduced.

Comment: Have you web searched you title? That would demonstrate some research effort which may convince experets to invest soem time. I did and I got https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jpclett.0c01960. The answers are there I believe.

Comment: I've updated my answer hopefully someone might take the time to come up with something. Even if it has a slim chance of working.

Comment: Ethanol freezes at 159.2K, far above any temperature where laser doppler cooling is relevant. It will also stick to any crystal. It does not have a "d line".  I think laser doppler cooling of larger molecules is leading edge science and you need to be a well equipped scientist to perform it. Have looked at the paper? It is from last July and its  title is "Toward Ultracold Organic Chemistry: Prospects of Laser Cooling Large Organic Molecules". Towards means that we're not there yet.